# How to add to status field user groups filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

- a system that allows me to publish statuses to my friends (i have friendship system too)

What I want:

- know how to create the groups (only `group name` necessary?)
- the statuses of group members could only be seen by the other members

Thanks a lot, if you need to see some of the code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and head for a many to many relationships between groups and users. You'll need a join table to pull them together. Then you can use group membership to decide who sees what in a quite straightforward manner.